# Load custom assembly in dialog

Tags: wixsharp

I'm using a custom dialog in a wixsharp setup console application project.

I've referenced 2 assemblies that I want to use in the custom dialog.
Whenever the dialog is loaded it tries to load the assemblies but fails.
An error that the files are not found is given.

Is it even possible to load custom assemblies in a custom dialog and how should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `EmbeddedAssembly` class is what you need to use. It embeds the assembly directly into the MSI file specifically for use in custom actions.